# What is the modal selection selection mode?

Tags: android, listview, modal-dialog, selection

When setting the selection mode of my `ListView` to multiple, I came across this constant introduced in Android API level 11: [CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL). The JavaDoc didn't help me out much:

> public static final int CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL
>
> The list allows multiple choices in a modal selection mode.

What is a modal selection mode? Can't find it nowheres.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is used to bring up an action mode (a.k.a., contextual action bar) when using action bars. You will see it in apps like Gmail: as you start checking items in the list, the action bar changes from generic activity-level actions to operations to be performed on the list (e.g., change labels, trash).

Like `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE`, you need your `ListView` to be populated by `Checkable` items. Then, though, once one or more items are checked, Android will automatically pop up your chosen action mode, which you can configure with your own actions.

Here is a sample project that demonstrates this: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionMode/ActionModeMC

Comment: What do you mean by populating the ListView by `Checkable` items? In your example, isn't it populated by `String`s?

Comment: @Maarten: The model data is strings. The *views*, however, are `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked`, which is a `CheckedTextView`, which implements the `Checkable` interface.

Comment: is there any way I can avoid contextual action bar?i tried setting it to false and then it didn't appear but then it seemed as if items were not being selected at all either....

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava: Sorry, but I do not understand. You may be better served asking a fresh Stack Overflow question.