# Is there any built-in "item checked listener" on Android ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I am using a ListView with `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` with an ArrayAdapter that shows a list of images. When I click in a list element, it gets checked and the image changes. Everything works just fine.

The image selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/check"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/uncheck"/>
</selector>
```

`ListView` has several methods regarding checked items (and I use them all), such as: `getCheckedItemPositions()`, `getCheckedItemCount()` and `setItemChecked(int position, boolean value)`.

However, it does not contain any method to set a listener for checked items, something like: `setOnItemCheckedListener` (`setOnItemSelectedListener` do not work for checking).

I implemented what I wanted using `OnClickListener`, but this is not ideal way (because it is not called when I use `setItemChecked`, for example). Is there any better solution?

Info: Android SDK: 23. Testing device: Android 5.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you create a method that acts as the OnItemSelectedListener (do whatever you want to do with the item checked) and call it from OnClickListener and setItemChecked (Override)?

As I said in the comments, the only listener that can be set is **setMultiChoiceModeListener()** which is only called if you set the choice mode of your listView to CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL. This is the only listener fired from methods such as setItemChecked().

From code documentation:

> A MultiChoiceModeListener receives events for {@link
>   AbsListView#CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL}.
>        It acts as the {@link ActionMode.Callback} for the selection mode and also receives
>        {@link #onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode, int, long, boolean)} events when the user
>        selects and deselects list items.

You can go with the doSomething() method called where you change the checkedState approach or change your choice mode to CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL and implement a setMultiChoiceModeListener() like this:

```
listview.setMultiChoiceModeListener(
    new MultiChoiceModeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            //DO SOMETHING

        }
    }
);
```

The CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL is well explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12713241/5837758 (and there's an example of MultiChoiceModeListener)

> This (CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL) is used to bring up an action mode
>   (a.k.a., contextual action bar) when using action bars. You will see
>   it in apps like Gmail: as you start checking items in the list, the
>   action bar changes from generic activity-level actions to operations
>   to be performed on the list (e.g., change labels, trash).

A third option would be to create a custom view/item for your list items and override the setChecked or setActivate methods, but I'll go with the listener approach.

Comment: You could also check the setMultiChoiceModeListener() mehtod

Comment: Put additional informations in your answer, i.e. edit your answer!

Comment: I know I could do this (and it is pretty much what I actually did), but this does not prevent any other case I may have forgotten (other ways to check items on the list). I am just wondering if there is any BUILT-IN method for this, as it seems that it should be the Android SDK.

Comment: I edited my answer, sorry guys I didn't have enough rep at the time. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ahhh thank you very much!! That's EXACTLY what I was looking for! I had no idea what was this multiple choice modal, I was just using multiple choice. And I was changing the action bar as well, and with this it gets much easier! This helped more than I expected.

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Comment: @Nikiole91 nice and clean..!